# How to query/ find a single element in a JSON array with linq.js

Tags: jquery, json, linq.js

I have a JSON array (javascript). I am using linq.js to filter/query the array and find a single element/first element. What is the correct syntax?

My data:

```
[{
    "Fname": "Chinmaya",
    "Lname": "Bhatta",
    "DOB": "/Date(328645800000)/",
    "PassportNumber": "",
    "Expirydate": "/Date(315513000000)/",
    "Mobilenum": "91-9740814702",
    "EmailID": "santu.yyyyy@yahoo.com",
    "IssueCountry": ""
},
    ...
]
```

My code:

```
var tbl =  $(this).closest('table');

var fname= $(tbl).find('[id*=txtFirstName]').val();

var lname= $(tbl).find('[id*=txtLastName]').val();

var filtered = Enumerable.From(fulllist)
                         .Select("$.Fname + ':'+ $.fname+")
                         .ToArray();
```

But it is throwing error. Can someone tell me what is the right syntax for querying based on Fname & Lname? BTW fulllist is the name of my array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/rk4N5/2)

Just like with a SQL query, you have to specify your 'where' clause to filter the results from the entire dataset:

```
var filtered = Enumerable
            .From(data)
            .Where("$.Fname == '" + fname + "' && $.Lname == '" + lname + "'")
            .Select("$.Fname + ':' + $.Lname + ':' + $.DOB")
            .ToArray();
```

You can also use the explicit form of the `Where` syntax which accepts a callback function:

```
Where(function (x) { return x.Fname == fname && x.Lname == lname });
```

---

**Edit**

To have your filtered result set be an array of JS obects, remove the call to `Select` ([***jsFiddle 2***](http://jsfiddle.net/rk4N5/3/)):

```
var filtered = Enumerable
               .From(data)
               .Where("$.Fname == '" + fname + "' && $.Lname == '" + lname + "'")
               .ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi nbrooks,
   thank you for quick response. It returns all the matching values. Actually I wanted only one row/one record only. Second, how to access the data of the single record in javascript code?

Comment: Hi nbrooks, this method, only returns the values, not the filed names. I wanted it like {"Fname": "Chinmaya", "Lname": "Bhatta"} format. But I am getting only the values. Pls help me out.

Comment: @santubangalore Do you want your result to be a string, or an object? See edit above, which returns the result as an object.

Comment: Hi nbrooks, thanks, my second problem is solved by this, but the first problem still remains. i.e. I wanted only one row/record, but I am getting multiple rows. How do I filter it to only one row? And access the data items from javascript code?

Comment: @santu My demo above is filtering the resultset to a single row, and is also logging the result (with JavaScript) to the console. If something isn't working, please edit your question to describe both the expected and actual results, and edit the jsfiddle (or make your own) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi nbrooks, thanks.  am still stuck on one last point, though. It is the date values. How do I convert them to dates/ how do i display those values in textboxes. Does it matter that my textboxes are bound to Jquery datePicker? I hv used syntax like: var birthdate= new Date(filtered[0].DOB); $(tbl).find('[id*=txtDateOfBirth]').val(birthdate); But it is displaying NaN.